# Add options in a dropdown via another function

Tags: javascript, html, function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjIvg.png)

this is what the user sees. I have to do in such a way that when I click on the second dropdown, that is the one of the months, I update the first one and insert the numbers according to the month that is selected. Example: January 1 to 31, February 1 to 28 and so on.
below I put the code of what I did.

```js
function paginaita()
{
document.getElementById('ita').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('ing').style.display="none";
}

function paginaing()
{
document.getElementById('ita').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('ing').style.display="block";
}

 function giorno() {
  document.getElementById('mese');
  if (mese == 1){
  var option = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"]
  }
   
 }
/*
var gg31 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"];
var gg30 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"];
var gg29 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29"];
var gg28 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"];
*/
```

```css
#sfondo{
background-color:#767676;
}

#font{
font-size: 35px;
font-family: arial;
}

#bandieraita{
 margin-left:860px;
 width:35px;
 height: 22.5px;
}

#bandieraing{
 margin-left:110px;
 width:35px;
 height: 22.5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<form id="ita">
<body id="sfondo" onload="paginaita()">
<center>
<div id="cambia">
<font id="font">
Inserisci la tua data di nascita
</font>

<br><br>
<select name="giorno" id="giorno">
</select>
<select name="Mese" onchange="giorno()">
<option value="1" id="mese">1</option>
<option value="2" id="mese">2</option>
<option value="mese" id="mese">3</option>
<option value="mese" id="mese">4</option>
<option value="mese" id="mese">5</option>
<option value="mese" id="mese">6</option>
<option value="mese" id="mese">7</option>
<option value="mese" id="mese">8</option>
<option value="mese" id="mese">9</option>
<option value="mese" id="mese">10</option>
<option value="mese" id="mese">11</option>
<option value="mese" id="mese">12</option>
</select>
<select name="Anno" id="anno">
<option value="anno">2019</option>
<option value="anno">2018</option>
<option value="anno">2017</option>
<option value="anno">2016</option>
<option value="anno">2015</option>
<option value="anno">2014</option>
<option value="anno">2013</option>
<option value="anno">2012</option>
<option value="anno">2011</option>
<option value="anno">2010</option>
<option value="anno">2009</option>
<option value="anno">2008</option>
<option value="anno">2007</option>
<option value="anno">2006</option>
<option value="anno">2005</option>
<option value="anno">2004</option>
<option value="anno">2003</option>
<option value="anno">2002</option>
<option value="anno">2001</option>
<option value="anno">2000</option>
<option value="anno">1999</option>
<option value="anno">1998</option>
<option value="anno">1997</option>
<option value="anno">1996</option>
<option value="anno">1995</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="document.getElementById('cambia').innerHTML = '<br>Inserimento avvenuto correttamente'">Conferma ✔</button>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
</center>
<img src="Immagini/itflag.gif" id="bandieraita" onclick="paginaita()">
<img src="Immagini/ukflagbw.gif" id="bandieraing" onclick="paginaing()">
</form>

<form id="ing">
<body id="sfondo">
<center>
<div id="cambia2">
<font id="font">
Enter your date of birth
</font>

<br><br>
<select name="Mese">
<option value="mese">January</option>
<option value="mese">February</option>
<option value="mese">March</option>
<option value="mese">April</option>
<option value="mese">May</option>
<option value="mese">June</option>
<option value="mese">July</option>
<option value="mese">August</option>
<option value="mese">September</option>
<option value="mese">October</option>
<option value="mese">November</option>
<option value="mese">December</option>
</select>
<select name="Giorno">
<option value="giorno">1</option>
<option value="giorno">2</option>
<option value="giorno">3</option>
<option value="giorno">4</option>
<option value="giorno">5</option>
<option value="giorno">6</option>
<option value="giorno">7</option>
<option value="giorno">8</option>
<option value="giorno">9</option>
<option value="giorno">10</option>
<option value="giorno">11</option>
<option value="giorno">12</option>
<option value="giorno">13</option>
<option value="giorno">14</option>
<option value="giorno">15</option>
<option value="giorno">16</option>
<option value="giorno">17</option>
<option value="giorno">18</option>
<option value="giorno">19</option>
<option value="giorno">20</option>
<option value="giorno">21</option>
<option value="giorno">22</option>
<option value="giorno">23</option>
<option value="giorno">24</option>
<option value="giorno">25</option>
<option value="giorno">26</option>
<option value="giorno">27</option>
<option value="giorno">28</option>
<option value="giorno">29</option>
<option value="giorno">30</option>
<option value="giorno">31</option>
</select>
<select name="Anno">
<option value="anno">2019</option>
<option value="anno">2018</option>
<option value="anno">2017</option>
<option value="anno">2016</option>
<option value="anno">2015</option>
<option value="anno">2014</option>
<option value="anno">2013</option>
<option value="anno">2012</option>
<option value="anno">2011</option>
<option value="anno">2010</option>
<option value="anno">2009</option>
<option value="anno">2008</option>
<option value="anno">2007</option>
<option value="anno">2006</option>
<option value="anno">2005</option>
<option value="anno">2004</option>
<option value="anno">2003</option>
<option value="anno">2002</option>
<option value="anno">2001</option>
<option value="anno">2000</option>
<option value="anno">1999</option>
<option value="anno">1998</option>
<option value="anno">1997</option>
<option value="anno">1996</option>
<option value="anno">1995</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="document.getElementById('cambia2').innerHTML = '<br>Your insertion has occurred correctly'">Submit ?</button>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
</center>
<img src="Immagini/itflagbw.gif" id="bandieraita" onclick="paginaita()">
<img src="Immagini/ukflag.gif" id="bandieraing" onclick="paginaing()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Embed your Javascript.js file in the <body> end instead of header. Because the function is being called before the DOM renders.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @David instead of creating arrays you can use `Date` object to get number of days in a month of a year. Below is the snippet for your reference.

```js
   
   function giorno(){
    //Get value of both year and month 
    var year = document.getElementById('anno').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('mese').value;

  //Get number of days in that month of year
    var date = new Date(year,month,0).getDate();
 
  var daySelect = document.getElementById('giorno'); 
  daySelect.innerHTML = '';
 
 //Append the new days
    for(var i=1;i<=date;i++){
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.text = i;
   option.value = i;
   daySelect.appendChild(option);
    }
   }
```

```html
 <select name="giorno" id="giorno">
   </select>
   <select name="Mese" id="mese" onchange="giorno()">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option>6</option>
   <option>7</option>
   <option>8</option>
   <option>9</option>
   <option>10</option>
   <option>11</option>
   <option>12</option>
   </select>
   <select name="Anno" id="anno" onchange="giorno()">
   <option>2019</option>
   <option>2018</option>
   <option>2017</option>
   <option>2016</option>
   <option>2015</option>
   <option>2014</option>
   <option>2013</option>
   <option>2012</option>
   <option>2011</option>
   <option>2010</option>
   <option>2009</option>
   <option>2008</option>
   <option>2007</option>
   <option>2006</option>
   <option>2005</option>
   <option>2004</option>
   <option>2003</option>
   <option>2002</option>
   <option>2001</option>
   <option>2000</option>
   <option>1999</option>
   <option>1998</option>
   <option>1997</option>
   <option>1996</option>
   <option>1995</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems with the code as written in the question:

1. An element's `id` attribute-value must be unique within the document; your `<option>` elements associated with the `<select name="Mese">` all have the `id="mese"` which renders your HTML invalid.
2. You're using the `<center>`, element which has been obsolete since the release of HTML 4 (1997-12-18) and XHTML 1 (2000-01-26); similarly you're using the `<font>` element which was deprecated in HTML 4.01 (around 1999-12).
3. You have two `<form>` elements doing the same thing, update one `<form>` rather than trying to manage multiple redundant elements.
4. Within the `<form>` element you have the `<body>` element; an HTML document may only have *one* `<body>` element, and that must wrap all content displayed to the user.

Having said the above, though, on to the fixed code; in this code I've done a few things:

1. Rearranged the `<select>` elements into year/month/day format,
2. Handled the changing month-names when the language is changed (this should be easily extendable),
3. Made the assumption that, if the user has already chosen the last day of January and then changes the month to February I've changed the selected day to be the last day of February. If the user selects day 5 then the selection is retained.

The code:

```js
// an object mapping a given language to month names in that language:
const months = {
    'en': ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    'it': ['Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre'],
  },
  // an object mapping a given language to the various instructions on the page, held
  // within <legend> elements in this demo:
  legends = {
    // the language key:
    'en': {
      // here the key is the id of the relevant <fieldset> element:
      'dataDiNascita': 'Enter your date of birth',
      'lingua': 'Select your country'
    },
    'it': {
      'dataDiNascita': 'Inserisci la tua data di nascita',
      'lingua': 'Seleziona il tuo paese'
    }
  }
// a simple function to find the maximum number of days in a given month:
daysInMonth = function(year, month) {
    // in the HTML you may see that the value of each month is one-based,
    // whereas in the Date Object the month is zero-based, while days are
    // one-based (because that's how the calendar works). Here we create
    // a new Date Object representing the month *after* the current month
    // but getting day 0 which is the last day of the previous month and
    // we then retrieve the date of that day:
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  },
  // a function to handle the language-change, using Arrow syntax as we're
  // not making use of any 'this':
  lingua = () => {

    // retrieving the <form> on the page:
    const form = document.querySelector('form'),
      // finding the checked <input> within the #lingua element and getting
      // its value:
      chosenLanguage = document.querySelector('#lingua input[name=country]:checked').value,
      // retrieving the <select name="Mese"> element:
      meseElement = document.querySelector('select[name=Mese]');
    // updating the lang property and attribute of the <form> (this may be important
    // for styling the form elements differently in languages that read right-to-left
    // or top-to-bottom):
    form.lang = chosenLanguage;
    // here we're finding all the <option> elements in the meseElement, and using
    // NodeList.forEach() to iterate over those elements:
    meseElement.querySelectorAll('option').forEach(
      // we're updating the text of the <option> elements here, via the
      // months Object; we find the Array of month-names with the key of the
      // chosen language and set the text equal to the String at the current
      // month-index:
      (opt, index) => opt.text = months[chosenLanguage][index]
    );
    document.querySelectorAll('fieldset').forEach(
      (fieldset) => fieldset.querySelector('legend').textContent = legends[chosenLanguage][fieldset.id]
    );
  },
  // creating a custom change event:
  changeEvent = new Event('change'),
  // another Arrow function to appropriately populate the days/Giorno element:
  populateDays = () => {
    // retrieving the selected year:
    const year = document.querySelector('select[name=Anno]').value,
      // retrieving the selected month:
      month = document.querySelector('select[name=Mese]').value,
      // using the daysInMonth() function to find the maximum days in the month:
      maxDays = daysInMonth(year, month),
      // retrieving the element that contains the days:
      daysElement = document.querySelector('select[name=Giorno]'),
      // finding the last <option> element within the daysElement:
      lastOption = daysElement.querySelector('option:last-child'),
      // getting the value (the day-number/Date) of the last day and
      // converting that into a Number using parseFloat:
      currentDays = parseFloat(lastOption.value),
      // retrieving the index of the currently selected <option>:
      selectedIndex = daysElement.selectedIndex,
      // finding the difference between maximum days of the current month
      // and the existing last-possible day:
      delta = maxDays - currentDays,
      // creating a document fragment in order to reduce page redraws:
      fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    // if the delta is negative, so we've selected a day that is higher than
    // the maximum number of days:
    if (delta < 0) {
      // here we find the elements that match the following selector:
      daysElement.querySelectorAll(
        // using a template-literal string allows us to use JavaScript
        // within the template-literal 'string'; here we're converting
        // the delta to the absolute value that :nth-last-child() expects
        // and we add 1 to that value, because we want to retrieve all
        // day elements that are impossible' in the current month, for
        // which we use the general-sibling ('~') combinator, selecting
        // all <option> elements following the option element that was
        // selected by :nth-last-child():
        `option:nth-last-child(${Math.abs(delta) + 1}) ~ option`
        // Using NodeList.forEach() to iterate over the retrieved elements:
      ).forEach(
        // option is a reference to the current <option> Node of the
        // NodeList that we're iterating over; here we simply use
        // ChildNode.remove() to remove each Node from the DOM:
        (option) => option.remove()
      );
      // otherwise if the delta is zero or more:
    } else {
      // we use a for loop to create the required number of new <option>
      // elements:
      for (i = 0; i < delta; i++) {
        // we append each newly-created <option> to the document fragment;
        fragment.append(
          // we use the new Option() syntax to create the new <option>
          // elements; here we set the text of the new <option> to be
          // equal to the number of the current last-date plus one (so that
          // it doesn't repeat the current last-date) plus the i variable
          // which iterates from zero (on first run) to the delta variable:
          new Option(currentDays + 1 + i)
        );
      }
      // appending the document fragment to the daysElement node:
      daysElement.appendChild(fragment);
    }
    // if the user selects the 31st of January, but then changes the month
    // to February we have a number of options:
    // 1. make no assumptions and forget the user-selection, or
    // 2. make the assumption that the user chose end-of-month deliberately
    //    and would make the same end-of-month choice next time, or
    // 3. assume that the user would choose the beginning of the month to be
    //    closer to the end-of-month they originally chose.
    // I chose option 2, but any other choice is perfectly valid
    if (selectedIndex > maxDays) {
      // here we retrieve the last <option> within the daysElement and
      // set its selected property to true:
      daysElement.querySelector('option:last-child').selected = true;
    }
  };

// here we retrieve all <input> elements within the #lingua element, and
// iterate over them with NodeList.forEach():
document.querySelectorAll('#lingua input').forEach(
  // 'el' is a reference to the current element-node of the NodeList
  // we're iterating over:
  (el) => {
    // here we bind the lingua() function - note the deliberate lack of
    // parentheses - as the event-handler for the 'change' event:
    el.addEventListener('change', lingua);
    // here we dispatch the created changeEvent (above) in order that the
    // month-names are properly set on page-load:
    el.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
  });

// here we retrieve the <select> elements whose names are 'Anno' or 'Mese':
// iterating over them with NodeList.forEach():
document.querySelectorAll('select[name="Anno"], select[name="Mese"]').forEach(
  // select is a reference to the current <select> element Node of the NodeList
  // over which we're iterating; here we're binding the populateDays() function
  // - again, note the deliberate lack of parentheses - as the 'change' event
  // for the <select> elements:
  (select) => select.addEventListener('change', populateDays)
)
```

```css
fieldset {
  text-align: center;
  border: 0px none transparent;
}

legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

legend::after {
  content: ':';
}

#lingua input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

label input+span::before {
  font-size: 3em;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  transition: filter 0.3s linear;
}

label:hover input+span::before,
label input:checked+span::before {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

.gb input+span::before {
  content: '';
}

.it input+span::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset id="dataDiNascita">
    <legend>Enter your date of birth</legend>
    <select name="Anno">
      <option>2019</option>
      <option>2018</option>
      <option>2017</option>
      <option>2016</option>
      <option>2015</option>
      <option>2014</option>
      <option>2013</option>
      <option>2012</option>
      <option>2011</option>
      <option>2010</option>
      <option>2009</option>
      <option>2008</option>
      <option>2007</option>
      <option>2006</option>
      <option>2005</option>
      <option>2004</option>
      <option>2003</option>
      <option>2002</option>
      <option>2001</option>
      <option>2000</option>
      <option>1999</option>
      <option>1998</option>
      <option>1997</option>
      <option>1996</option>
      <option>1995</option>
    </select>
    <select name="Mese">
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
      <option value="3">March</option>
      <option value="4">April</option>
      <option value="5">May</option>
      <option value="6">June</option>
      <option value="7">July</option>
      <option value="8">August</option>
      <option value="9">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="Giorno">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>11</option>
      <option>12</option>
      <option>13</option>
      <option>14</option>
      <option>15</option>
      <option>16</option>
      <option>17</option>
      <option>18</option>
      <option>19</option>
      <option>20</option>
      <option>21</option>
      <option>22</option>
      <option>23</option>
      <option>24</option>
      <option>25</option>
      <option>26</option>
      <option>27</option>
      <option>28</option>
      <option>29</option>
      <option>30</option>
      <option>31</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="lingua">
    <legend>
      Select your country
    </legend>
    <label class="gb">
      <input type="radio" name="country" value="en" checked>
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="it">
      <input type="radio" name="country" value="it">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h29scnpk/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [General-sibling (`~`) combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).
  - [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).
  - [`:nth-last-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).
  - [`Date()` Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
  - [`Document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).
  - [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
  - [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Event()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
  - [`NodeList.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
  - [`Option()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option).
  - [`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append).
  - [`ParseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
  - [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Bibliography:

- "[Creating and triggering custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)," MDN.